# How to count subscribers in RAC

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm a newbie to RAC. I have a RACSubject object, and I send events manually. Some classes subscribe to this RACSubject. How can I know that all subscribers are deallocated, to perform some code. Is there some mechanism in ReactiveCocoa?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The signal sender should not care about who and when it is subscribed.

Comment: I'm implementing webSocket client. There are subscriptions at the server side. I need to send message <subscribe to some event> via my gateway class, and some different controllers will subscribe to this event. When none of controllers need this data more, I need to send message <unsubscribe to some event>.

Comment: How do you make a controller unsubscribe the signal? By disposing?

Comment: Yes. When I don't need more this event in the controller, I dispose the subscription.